# Velocity.js UI pack effects not applying with Blast.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I am using Velocity UI pack along with Blast.js(for manipulating text). Basic stuff, put the delimiter option to character and then animate using UI pack with stagger and pre-build effects.

The problem is that no matter what effect I use, I always get the fade-out effect.

On the same page I have a logo split in three pieces, and all of the effects work like a charm there. Of course there is no Blast.js involved there.

Here is the code used:

```
     // animate text
        $('.logo-text-1, .logo-text-2').blast({delimiter : 'character'}).velocity("transition.bounceUpOut", { 
            stagger: 60,
            delay: 1000,
            complete: function () {
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
            $('.spinner').fadeOut();
            }
          });

        // animate logo
        $('.logo-piece').velocity('transition.slideRightBigOut', {
        stagger: 150,
        delay: 1500
     })
```

Additionally, here is a link to the test website:
http://madebym.me/test/polar-publishing/

Answer (score 0):

Seems I missed something trivial. I forgot to add this to the CSS.

```
.blast{display: inline-block;opacity: 1;}
```